# Rotation of an array

Tags: c++

This is a C++ code and I feel its correct, yet it doesn't work.

I will explain a bit for understanding

`t` - number of tries.
`n` - size of array.
`k` - number of rotation.

Input: `1 2 3 4 5` .

for `k=2`, Output: `4 5 1 2 3`.

Please advise on the same.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t,n,k;
    cin >> t;
    int s = 0;
    int a[1000];
    int b[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin >> n;  //TAKING IN THE NUMBER OF ELEMENTS.
        cin >> k;  // TAKING IN AMOUNT OF ROTATION.
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cin >> a[j];  //READING ARRAY.
            cout << " ";
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
            b[y + k] = a[y];  // REARRANGING ARRAY.
            if (y + k >= n) {
                b[s] = a[y];
                s++;
            }
            cout << b[y] << " "; // SHOWING ARRAY.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Also please clean up the question formatting, it is really hard to read the way you posted.

Comment: The input `1 2 3 4 5` with k=2 does not match up with how the program consumes the input.

Comment: First make sure you enable extra warnings, and then tread the warnings as errors. Then please [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). And some indentation to make it easier to read might be good as well.

Comment: Finally, unless this is for an exercise where you have to write the rotation yourself, learn about [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code, that should help make the bug very obvious.  I simplified the code, and the last for-loop's bugs (plural) stood out.

Comment: If you used b better variable names you wouldn't have to explain their uses.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. But i am still looking for finding the reason behind the code to not work properly . I will improve the formatting and try to make it more readable;

Comment: [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: If you used better variable names, you wouldn't have to explain them.  For example, `number_of_tries`, `array_capacity` and `number_of_rotations`.  The length of variable names should not affect the online judges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem with your code is in line,

```
cout<<b[y]<<" "; // SHOWING ARRAY.
```

You must take it out of that for loop,since you are trying to print something that you have not given value.For example,first y=0 you set b[y+2] but you print b[y] which is not yet set.

Another problem which you will see for t>1  is initialisation of s has been done out of main i.e it is 0 for only first run.

the final code will be

#include

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int t;
cin>>t;
int n;
int k;

int a[1000];
int b[1000];
for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
{
    int s=0; //Changed
    cin>>n;  
    cin>>k;  
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
  cin>>a[j]; 
 // cout<<" ";  //Not needed
    }
for(int y=0;y<n;y++)
 {
   b[y+k]=a[y];  
   if(y+k>=n)
   {
   b[s]=a[y];
   s++;
   }
//cout<<b[y]<<" "; // changed this
 }
 for(int y=0;y<n;y++)         //added this
 cout<<b[y]<<" ";
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am so very great full for your insight and guidance on my problem, your solutions has resolved my problem and at the same time realize my mistake.Thank you.